# Name einer rhetorischen Figur gesucht

Tags: rhetoric

Es geht um eine Sonderform des Zeugmas (Syllepse):

> Ich setze mich an den Tisch und mir die Kopfhörer auf.

Hier werden zwei Hauptsätze mit der Konjunktion *»und«* verbunden. Das Verb des ersten Satzes ist *»setzen«*, das des zweiten Satzes ist aber das trennbare Verb *»aufsetzen«*. Die Verwendung im Präsens erzwingt die Trennung des Verbs in seine beiden Bestandteile, und das macht es wiederum möglich, den Stamm des zweiten Satzes als eigenständiges Verb zu interpretieren, und es insgesamt nur einmal zu setzen.

Das nächste Beispiel ist ähnlich, aber das Verb, das hier in beiden Sätzen vorkommt, ist dasselbe (*ziehen*):

> Johanna zog nach Paris und Walter an seiner Zigarre.

Das gleiche Verb kann auch trennbar sein (*eintreten*):

> Heinz trat die Tür und Robert in den Kegelklub ein.

So eine Figur nennt man, wenn ich Wikipedia richtig verstanden habe, [Zeugma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_(Sprache)) oder [Syllepse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse). Allerdings scheint es so zu sein, dass dabei, wie in meinen beiden letzen Beispielen, die beiden Teile jeweils *dasselbe* Verb (in zwei verschiedenen Bedeutungen) enthalten müssen, wovon dann eines weggelassen wird.

In meinem ersten Satz ist das aber nicht der Fall. *»Setzen«* und *»aufsetzen«* sind zwei verschiedene Wörter.

Gibt es für diesen Sonderfall eine besondere Bezeichnung?

Comment: kurz: wahrscheinlich nicht, weil die alten Griechen keine trennbaren Verben kannten. Ich glaube, das ist einfach auch ein Zeugma. Das klassische Beispiel "Ich heiße Heinz Erhard und sie herzlich willkommen" eines deutschen Zeugma hat auch ein sozusagen trennbares Verb.

Comment: Der verlinkte WP-Artikel nennt sowohl tofros Beispiel als auch „Er trat die Tür ein und den Rückweg an.“ In beiden kommt nicht dasselbe (im Sinne Deiner Frage) Verb vor. Ich stimme also tofro zu: es ist ein Zeugma.

Comment: Mit Verlaub der WP-Artikel scheint nicht das Gelbe vom Ei zu sein und enthält nicht gerade viele Belege, würde ich also nicht als Weisheit letzter Schluss sehen. ;-)

Comment: @Thomas: Du kannst sowohl den Wikipedia-Artikel verbessern, als auch uns dein Wissen hier offenbaren. Nörgeln allein hilft niemandem.

Comment: Meine Wehklagen waren auch nur die eines vertrockneten Geistes, dennoch warnend sich dem scheinbar Erklärten zufrieden zu geben. Aber deine Frage hat auch meine Neugier geweckt, alleine es fehlt die Zeit für eine gründliche Recherche. Der englische Artikel ist da deutlich umfangreicher...

Comment: @Thomas: Ich kann in dem englischen Wikipediaartikel aber keinen Hinweis auf deutsche trennbare Verben finden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nein, diese Variante läuft auch unter den genannten Begriffen. Das kann man auch schon bei Wikipedia nachlesen (siehe "unterschiedliche Partikel").